# A linear operator on the space of all sequences that cannot be thought of as matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

This not homework but a general question about how to think about linear operators on not so nice spaces.

Consider the space of all real-valued sequences $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}$ and a linear operator $T \colon \mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}} \to \mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}$ defined on it.
Can it happen that
$$
T(\sum_{j \in \mathbb{N}} \alpha_j e_j) \neq \sum_{j \in \mathbb{N}} \alpha_j T(e_j)
$$ holds (where $e_j$ is the sequence which is 1 at index $j$ and 0 elsewhere)?

What about the case where we assume that $T$ is symmetric, i.e. $(T e_j)_i = (T e_i)_j$?

Comment: Effectively, we have a quantity $T (\lim _n \sum ^n \alpha _je_j)$, which alludes to some kind of topology. In the usual sequence spaces the distributive property holds when $T$ is bounded. I'm not sure how this works without any mention of topology.

Comment: No, it doesn't allude to a topology in this case: $\sum_{j \in \mathbb{N}} \alpha_j e_j$ is just the sequence which has $\alpha_j$ as its $j$-th entry.
I'm also not sure and that is precisely why I'm asking here: maybe there is someone who does know.

Comment: Although, the right hand side should be interpreted somehow. Let's say it is meant in the pointwise/coordinatewise sense.

Comment: If in the left that notation stands simply for the sequence... what does it stand for on the right?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez The pointwise limit if it exists. Observe that this limit at the $i$-th coordinate can only exist if there are only finitely many $j$ such that $T(e_j)_i$ is nonzero. In particular, in the symmetric case every $e_j$ has to be mapped to a sequence which is nonzero only for finitely many coordinates.

Comment: And if it does not exist? The ei's are not a basis, so that finiteness you mention does not really hold.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Then you have a counterexample. I still don't know how to construct such an operator in the symmetric case I mentioned.

Comment: I still don't know what you are asking.

Comment: Then you're probably not able to answer it anyway? Maybe make more explicit what you do not understand so I can make it more clear.

Comment: The question is, formulated in another way without worrying about convergence: Can you find a symmetric linear operator $T \colon \mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}} \to \mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}$ such that there is a $j$ such that $Te_j$ is not of finite support?

Comment: Pick *any* infinite matrix: there is a linear map that sends ei to the ith column of the matrix.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez How is that map defined for all (other) elements of $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}$? I doesn't extend by linearity because $(e_j)_j$ is not a basis..

Comment: Simply extend the set of the ei to a basis and map the other basis elements to zero.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Ah yes, that is the thought I was missing. Thank you very much! If you make an answer out of that I would happily accept it. (Still a very scary counterexample, i.e. makes the existence of a Hamel basis even more unintuitive for me).

Comment: As you insist on an example: Let $c$ be the subspace of $\mathbb R^{\mathbb N}$ consisting of all convegernt sequences and define $T:c\to \mathbb R^{\mathbb N}$ as $T(x)=(\lim x, 0,0,\ldots)$ and then extend $T$ in a linear way to all of $\mathbb R^{\mathbb N}$ (this of course needs a Hamel basis of $\mathbb R^{\mathbb N}$ or some related stuff like Zorn's lemma). Then $T(1,1,1\ldots)=(1,0,0,\ldots)$ but $\sum_jT(e_j) =(0,0,0,\ldots)$ since $T(e_j)=0\in \mathbb R^{\mathbb N}$ (which also shows the symmetry you asked for).

Answer (score 1):

The space $ V = \mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N} $ is indeed a vector space, but without topology, the sequence of vectors $ e_i $ is not in any sense a basis for $ V $.  For example the vector $ \xi = \langle 1, 1, 1 \ldots \rangle $ is not a (finite) linear combination of the $ e_i $.  So even if you have already specified coefficients $ \alpha_{ij} $ with $ T e_i = \sum \alpha_{ij} e_j $, you are free to define $ T \xi $ however you want, without contradiction.

You can, however, find an *uncountable* Hamel basis for $ V $ (look up Hamel basis on Wikipedia).  Call this basis $\langle \xi_i\rangle_{i \in I}$ for some uncountable indexing set $ I $.  You can then write down coefficients $ \alpha_{ij} $ for $ (i,j) \in I \times I $, with $ \alpha_{ij} = 0 $ for all but at most finitely many $ j $ for each fixed $ i $, and then you can, in a sense, have a "matrix" representation of $ T $ where

$$
T \left( \sum_{i \in I} c_i \xi_i \right) = \sum_{i \in I} {
  \sum_{j \in I} { c_i \alpha_{ij} \xi_j}
}
$$
for when all but finitely many $ c_i $ are zero.  Notice, all sums on both sides are finite by assumption.  I should warn you, this is not of any practical utility known to me.  The construction of the uncountable Hamel basis uses the axiom of choice, which should divorce it from any practical application.

Comment: That doesn't answer the question. In particular, $T\xi$ can not be freely defined however I want, because the operator still has to be linear (and symmetric).
I'm fully aware that this isn't a real basis. Still I want to find a counterexample (in the symmetric case).

Comment: @unwissen The vector $\xi$ is linearly independent from the $e_i$'s. So you can define $T(e_i)$, $i \in \mathbb{N}$, and $T(\xi)$ completely freely however you want and extend this to a linear map on all of $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$.

Answer (score 0):

As comments pointed out, first thing would be to define properly. But i think what you said can happen, Lets say $T$ is linear operator with domain on the set of all convergent sequences in $\mathbb{R}$. Then define $$T(\{s_n\}) = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} s_n$$. Let $s_n = 1-1/n$. Then $T(\{s_n\}) = 1$ and $T(s_i e_i) = 0$ where $e_i$ is the sequence with $1$ at $i^{th}$ position and $0$ at other places. Hence we have $\lim_{\ell \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{i=1}^{\ell} T(s_ie_i) = 0$ but $T(\{s_n\}) = T(\lim_{\ell \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{i=1}^{\ell} s_i e_i) = 1$. See if this is useful.

Comment: Thanks, but doesn't get us any closer to an answer because the domain of your operator behaves very differently.

Comment: @unwissen what does not get us closer to an answer is mostly that the question is so imprecise that it is essentially unanswerable, really...